# unable to move an object to a thread

Tags: python-3.4, qthread, pyqt5

I'm currently building a small serial monitor. It's based on two main class: SerialSender and SerialListener. These run infinite loop, so they should be placed in theyr own thread.

There is a minimal code reproducing the bad comportment of my programm:

```
sender = SerialSender()
listener = SerialListener()

sender_thread = QThread()
listener_thread = QThread()

sender.moveToThread(sender_thread)
listener.moveToThread(sender_thread)

print("Main thread is: {mt}\n"
      "Sender thread is: {st}\n"
      "Listener thread is: {lt}".format(
       mt = int(QThread.currentThreadId()),
       st = int(sender.thread().currentThreadId()),
       lt = int(listener.thread().currentThreadId()))
```

With this code, we can expect to have three different thread ids, but I get:

```
Main thread is: 139968246126400
Sender thread is: 139968246126400
Listener thread is: 139968246126400
```

Where does this come from ?

Comment: "minimal" is quite a euphemism: the code does not even work since an ending parenthesis is missing. Once fixed, I get this error: " NameError: name 'SerialSender' is not defined " ... please provide the whole code otherwise it will be impossible to help.

Comment: `currentThreadId` is static, returns the id of the thread that calls it. i.e. you're printing the same thing in three different ways.